# Flutter: Can I combine lists into anything else?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a flutter newbie, trying to make an oil calculator on my own for the first time; I have three lists, date, oilBuy, and price, but Listview. Builder can get data from only one source, and saving, viewing, or deleting data from 3 separate lists is not a good idea as I think I'm sharing my code; can anyone help me minimize it?

```
  TextEditingController datesController = TextEditingController();
  List oilBuy = [];
  TextEditingController oilBuyController = TextEditingController();
  List price = [];
  TextEditingController priceController = TextEditingController();
  List km = [];
  TextEditingController kmController = TextEditingController();
 
//For printing them...I am using columns inside a row to view.  

     Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text('Date'),
                      for (int i = 0; i < dates.length; i++)
                        (dates.isNotEmpty)
                            ? Text(dates[i].toString())
                            : Text("")
                    ],
                  ),
```

Comment: Hey @ferdous. Welcome to SO. Could you elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to achieve, because it seems unclear from the question. Maybe a rough layout or wirefrrame?

Comment: I'm not clear about the question, but I think you can create a data model class to handle it

Comment: Can you please explain the question briefly

Answer (score 0):

From your question, you can create an data model class and update your available data into model class and get it as an single model list. Then you can have a single listview.builder and edit/view/delete can be handled there.